# Where is the code that creates the Layout shape in Orchard CMS?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

We are trying to understand the Orchard request life cycle by reading this  [blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2011/03/29/what-happens-when-i-request-a-page-in-orchard.aspx) by Bertrand Le Roy. We were able to step through the code and to create a diagram of paragraph one, which describes the creation of a Shape for a specific route. Good.

### Sequence Diagram of Paragraph One

[image]

### Relevant Code from Paragraph One

```
public ActionResult Display(int id) {
    var contentItem = 
        _contentManager.Get(id, VersionOptions.Published);

    if (contentItem == null)
        return HttpNotFound();

    if (!Services.Authorizer.Authorize(Permissions.ViewContent, 
            contentItem, 
            T("Cannot view content"))) {
        return new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
    }

    dynamic model = _contentManager.BuildDisplay(contentItem);
    return new ShapeResult(this, model);
}
```

### In Paragraph Three We Get Stuck

In the third paragraph of his post, Bertrand talks about the Layout shape.

> One very important shape **already exists** at this point on the work
>   context, and that is the **Layout shape.**

OK. So it already exists. When was it created, and where is the code that creates it?

Comment: I think you should try asking your questions on the [Orchard codeplex forums](http://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/), there is probably a more specialised (to orchard) and active community there and you're more likely to get a good answer.

Comment: No, SO is just fine to get answers. I think the trouble here is more in the question style that is not a great fit for SO, as it's imprecise and unlikely to get precise and useful answers rather than a discussion.
It would be interesting to understand what you are trying to do. For example, why does it matter to you when and where the layout shape is created?

Comment: Post your findings as an answer at least :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Betrand Le Roy answered in a [codeplex discussion](https://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/441882).

> [The Layout shape is] created by the work context the first time it's needed (look at
>   the Layout property accessor there).

His answer refers to this code:

```
public dynamic Layout {
    get { return GetState<object>("Layout"); }
    set { SetState("Layout", value); }
}
```